# Match or remove string that occurs multiple times within two strings with regex

Tags: regex, pcre

I have a large csv export where the columns do not align because some values are accidentally put in multiple cells instead of one. Fortunately, the values lay between two unique strings. I am hoping to use regex to merge these values into one cell. Sample data is as follows:

```
"apple","NULL","0","0","0",",","1",",","fruit","red","sweet","D$","object"
"horse","NULL","0","0","0",",","1",",","animal","large","tail","D$","object"
"Los Angeles","NULL","0","0","0",",","1",","city","California","smoggy","entertainment","D$","location"
```

The unmerged values begin after

```
"NULL","0","0","0",",","1",",","
```

And the unmerged values end before

```
","D$"
```

I'm trying to figure out a regex that would remove the "," between the values to merge them, so the output would look like:

```
"apple","NULL","0","0","0",",","1",",","fruit,red,sweet","D$","object"
"horse","NULL","0","0","0",",","1",",","animal,large,tail","D$","object"
"Los Angeles","NULL","0","0","0",",","1",",","city,California,smoggy,entertainment","D$","location"
```

Comment: Is it normal that you csv breaks here `"1",","fruit` or is it a typo?

Comment: That was a typo -- corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that:

```
$pattern = '~(?:"NULL","0","0","0",",","1",",","|(?!^)\G)[^"]+\K","(?!D\$)~';
$csv = preg_replace($pattern, ',', $csv);
```

pattern details:

```
~             # delimiter
(?:
    "NULL","0","0","0",",","1",",","
  |           
    (?!^)\G   # anchor for the end of the last match
)
[^"]+         # content between quotes
\K            # removes all on the left from match result
","           # ","
(?!D\$)       # not followed by D$
~
```

The idea of the pattern is to use the `\G` anchors that means "start of the string" or "end of the last match". I added `(?!^)` to avoid the first case.

`"NULL","0","0","0",",","1",",","` is used as an entry point for the first match. Then the content between quotes is matched. Since the `\K` removes all on the left from the match result, only `","` is replaced.

The next matches use `\G` as entry point and the contiguous matches continue until `(?!D\$)` succeeds.

Comment: That did it! Thank you for the quick response and explanation.

Comment: @Sam: `\K` can be useful to emulate a variable length lookbehind too.

Answer (score 0):

The best I was able to do in RegEx is just match the entire string of values, but not get them into capturing groups.  This means I wasn't able to just match/replace without a callback function.  Depending on your language, you'll have to do this differently, but I'll show an example in PHP.  Here is the [regex](http://regex101.com/r/rE0fY4):

```
(?<="NULL","0","0","0",",","1",",)(?:"[^"]+",?)+(?=,"D\$")
```

First, we start by looking behind (`(?<=...)`) for your `"NULL","0","0","0",",","1",",` string.  Then we use a non-capturing repeated group (`(?:...)+`) that will catch 1+ CSV columns.  The syntax inside matches `"`, followed by 1+ non-`"` characters, followed by `"` and an optional `,`.  Findally, we look ahead (`(?=...)`) for your `,"D\$"` string which ends the list of words.

Given this string:

```
"apple","NULL","0","0","0",",","1",","fruit","red","sweet","D$","object"
```

It will match:

```
"fruit","red","sweet"
```

---

In PHP, I used `preg_replace_callback()` to loop through each match and then I replace all instances of `","` with `,`.  When `$csv` equals your sample data, this gives you your intended output.

```
$csv = preg_replace_callback(
    '/(?<="NULL","0","0","0",",","1",",)(?:"[^"]+",?)+(?=,"D\$")/',
    function($matches) {
        return str_replace('","', ',', reset($matches));
    },
    $csv
);
```

Output:

> "apple","NULL","0","0","0",",","1",","fruit,red,sweet","D$","object"
>
> "horse","NULL","0","0","0",",","1",","animal,large,tail","D$","object"
>
> "Los Angeles","NULL","0","0","0",",","1",","city,California,smoggy,entertainment","D$","location"

---

**Note:** The reason I don't think I am able to do this in one simple regex replace is because (to my knowledge) regex isn't good at capturing X groups.  If, for instance, we replaced the repeated non-capturing group with something like `(?:"([^"]+)",?)+` (added a capture group around the word, `[^"]+`), it would still only count as 1 captured group.  See [this example](http://regex101.com/r/dD7gP5) to see what I mean.  You could literally repeat that non-capturing group, and make each one after the first optional with `?`.  However, you'd have to include *at least* as many as your largest example (see [here](http://regex101.com/r/pE0rU7)).