# How to put two regexs together

Tags: php, regex

I'm stumped. I've got two regexs that are doing what I need individually, but I'm not sure how to get them to work in conjunction.

`\b([a-zA-Z])?\d{5}\b` is correctly finding strings in the pattern of an optional single letter followed by 5 digits.

`<a\s+(?:[^>]*?\s+)?href="([^"]*)"` is matching the URL in an anchor tag.

Now what I want to match on (for replacement purposes) is the 5 digit number (with or without the preceding letter) that occur within the URL of an anchor tag.

Sample content:

`<a href="/uploads/2014/04/Draft-99990-Details.doc">Draft 99995 Details</a>
<a href="/uploads/2014/04/01090-vs-G01010-series.pdf">01095 vs G01015 Series</a>`

There should be 3 matches in this text, the 3 numbers ending in 0 and not those ending in 5.

Comment: What is the "link portion" of an anchor tag.  Is that the actual URL or the text inside the tag (I'm assuming the URL)?

Comment: The URL, what's between the quotes after "href=". Sorry I worded that strangely. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the task into two. First, retrieve all the `href` attribute contents using a DOM parser such as PHP's DOMDocument, and then use a regular expression to replace the specific part. The advantage of this method over a single regular expression is that, it won't break even if the format of your markup changes in future.

```
$html = <<<HTML
<a href="/uploads/2014/04/Draft-99990-Details.doc">Draft 99995 Details</a>
<a href="/uploads/2014/04/01090-vs-G01010-series.pdf">01095 vs G01015 Series</a>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$replacement = 'FOO';
$html = '';

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node) {
    $href = $node->getAttribute('href');
    $node->setAttribute('href', preg_replace('/([a-z])?\d{5}/i', $replacement, $href));
    $html .= $dom->saveHTML($node);
}

echo $html;
```

Output:

```
<a href="/uploads/2014/04/Draft-FOO-Details.doc">Draft 99995 Details</a>
<a href="/uploads/2014/04/FOO-vs-FOO-series.pdf">01095 vs G01015 Series</a>
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/143416)

Comment: Finally getting some time to come back to this project. I've got your solution doing what I need it to, but how do I handle any HTML that's not a link? ie. if I have 'some content here <a href="<a href="/uploads/2014/04/Draft-99990-Details.doc">Draft 99995 Details</a> more text here
<a href="/uploads/2014/04/01090-vs-G01010-series.pdf">01095 vs G01015 Series</a> and some final text here'?

Comment: @SandboxWizard: I'm not sure what you mean by "handle". Are you trying to have it work with invalid HTML too? If so, what's the expected output in the above case?

Comment: To keep my example in the comment and the replacement from your example. The expected output is: 'some content here <a href="<a href="/uploads/2014/04/Draft-FOO-Details.doc">Draft 99995 Details</a> more text here <a href="/uploads/2014/04/FOO-vs-FOO-series.pdf">01095 vs G01015 Series</a> and some final text here'. So if I pass in the HTML content for a page I want to get that same content back, but with the replacements made in the anchor tags. Did that make sense?

Comment: `<a href="<a href="/uploads/2014/04/Draft-FOO-Details.doc">Draft 99995 Details</a>` is not valid HTML in the first place. How do you expect it to work? Is that a typo? Or just an intentional mistake? I'm not sure what you're asking. To me, it looks like a different problem. Maybe you want to post a new question explaining all the details and reference this one if required, @SandboxWizard.

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo. The content in my first comment should be: 
'some content here 
<a href="/uploads/2014/04/Draft-99990-Details.doc">Draft 99995 Details</a> 
more text here 
<a href="/uploads/2014/04/01090-vs-G01010-series.pdf">01095 vs G01015 Series</a> 
and some final text here' The HTML being passed I'm creating, so it will be valid.

Comment: @SandboxWizard I'm confused. The expected output doesn't make much sense. Can we take this to chat?

Comment: As I understand it the 'foreach' in your example code is pulling out all the anchor tags and doing the replace, then saving the HTML for that anchor tag to $html. Any other HTML in the original $html will be lost, correct?

Comment: @SandboxWizard: Yes, that is correct. This code currently only modifies the `href` attribute. If you want the entire document to be output as it is, except with the `href`s changed, you could simply use this: https://eval.in/154617

Answer (score 0):

This [expression](http://regex101.com/r/cM8uF2), should do the trick.

```
(?:<a\s+(?:[^>]*)?href="|(?!^)\G)\K.*?([A-Z]?\d{5})(?=.*?")
```

Explanation:

```
(?:                         # BEGIN non-capturing group
    <a\s+(?:[^>]*)?href="   # Anchor tag up until the href attribute
  |                         # OR
    (?!^)\G                 # \G finds the end of the last match
)                           # END non-capturing group
\K                          # Start match over (remove anchor tag from match)
.*?                         # Lazily match the URL
([A-Z]?\d{5})               # Capture an optional letter followed by 5 digits
(?=                         # BEGIN look ahead
    .*?"                    # Lazily match to the end of the URL
)                           # END look ahead
```

This is done with the `g` and `i` modifier for a global, case-insensitive match. Please note that this will only "match" to the end of the capture group (instead of the end of the URL).  This is because we have to use `\G` to find the end of the last match.  If we [match the entire URL](http://regex101.com/r/wJ6bM0), then the `\G` will start over at the end of the URL and we will miss some groups.

Hat tip to [Casimir's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23303623/703229).

Comment: In the unlikely event that the `href` attribute contains a `>` character, this would fail: `<a title="Download link for RandomSoftware version >= X.Y" `: http://regex101.com/r/dY1oD2

Comment: In that case, you can just replace `[^>]*` with a lazy match `.*?`.  But this does drive home the point that HTML [is not a regular language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).